# Sending file and text in node.js

Tags: node.js, server

I'm trying to build a simple web server in node.js.

The server need to receive an http GET command and send the requested file to the client with a response text.

The server send the response through socket.write() and a file through fileAsAstream.pipe() as follows:

```
// Write the response text
socket.write("Without me, the response will not be written "); // I don't want this line
socket.write(responseText.toString());
// Pipe the file, it works perfect
var fileAsAstream = fs.createReadStream(url));
fileAsAstream.pipe(socket);
```

The problem is - without the first socket.write() the response text (The second socket.write()) doesn't being sent to the client.
Now, it's look for me like a kind of a buffer. I tried to do socket.setNoDelay(true) but it didn't work.

How can i remove the first socket.write() so that the second socket.write() still be send?

Thanks!

Comment: `require('http').createServer(function(req,res){require('fs').createReadStream(__filename).pipe(res);});` works perfectly.  I see socket and I suspect you're using `require('net')` are you?

Comment: Yes, i'm using 'net'. Is there a way without using 'http'? Thanks!

Comment: Totally up to you, and i appreciate the desire for a simple no frills solution, but I suspect you might be quicker going with http than sticking with the basic approach if it needs a question on here...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I can't use http because it's an excercise that i received in university and we are forbidden to use http.